# Unexpected tikz/counter behaviour

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, loops, foreach

What I've been trying to do, futilely, is to use the `foreach[counter=\xi] x in {1,2,3}` statement in tikz/pgf with LaTeX. This fails, every time. Whatever. So I moved on to trying to use a counter, surely that would work. Here's a MWE that fails unexpectedly.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\newcounter{i}
\setcounter{i}{0}
\foreach \x in #1
{
\draw (0,\i) -- (1,0);
\setcounter{i}{\i+1}
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\test{{1,2,3}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code, at least for me, produces

[image]

Can anyone explain why? How I would fix this, or how I could actually get `foreach[counter=\xi]` to work without returning an `\inaccessible` exception upon compilation in pdfLaTeX

Comment: Using `\xi` as counter variable is not a good idea, at least if you also want to use the Greek letter ξ in your document (which becomes inaccessible after running the loop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the use of the counter macro. You may access its value by `\value{i}` instead of `\i`, you can increase it by `\stepcounter{i}` or `\addtocounter{i}{1}`. On the other hand you could use `\x` directly.

So try for example:

```
\setcounter{i}{0}
\foreach \x in #1
{
\draw (0,\value{i}) -- (1,0);
\stepcounter{i}
}
```

[image]

And without the additional counter it's just:

```
\foreach \x in #1
{
\draw (0,\x) -- (1,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Which version of TikZ are you using? The `count` (not `counter`) option was introduced in version 2.10 (sorry for not adding this info to my answer to your other question). If you are using TeX Live 2010, then a simple `tlmgr update --all` will (amongst others) update TikZ to the current version.